# Querying an array of objects

Tags: coffeescript

Anyone have guidance on how to query an array of hashes in coffeescript?

For example, I have an array of hashes, each with a "name" and "setting":

```
[
  {"name":"color", "setting":"red"},
  {"name":"scale_min", "setting":"15"},
  {"name":"scale_type", "setting":"linear"},
  {"name":"x_axis_label", "setting":"Weeks"}
]
```

I want to find the element in this array where the hash "name" is "x_axis_label"

How can I easily do that with coffeescript?

I need some kind of `value_for_key_in_object(key, object)` function and figured if would be part of the lexicon...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you going to do this repeatedly, always looking for things where the name equals something, then you are better off converting this from an array of maps to just a map where the key is the name.

```
data = [
  {"name":"color","setting":"red"}
  {"name":"scale_min","setting":"15"}
  {"name":"scale_type","setting":"linear"}
  {"name":"x_axis_label","setting":"Weeks"}
]

myMap = {}
for row in data
  myMap[row.name] = row.setting

alert(myMap['x_axis_label'])
```

[Demo](http://coffeescript.org/#try:data%20=%20%5B%0A%20%20%7B%22name%22:%22color%22,%22setting%22:%22red%22%7D%0A%20%20%7B%22name%22:%22scale_min%22,%22setting%22:%2215%22%7D%0A%20%20%7B%22name%22:%22scale_type%22,%22setting%22:%22linear%22%7D%0A%20%20%7B%22name%22:%22x_axis_label%22,%22setting%22:%22Weeks%22%7D%0A%5D%0A%0AmyMap%20=%20%7B%7D%0Afor%20row%20in%20data%0A%20%20myMap%5Brow.name%5D%20=%20row.setting%0A%0Aalert%28myMap%5B%27x_axis_label%27%5D%29)

Answer (score 32):

I just hacked this up quickly:

```
data = [{"name":"color","setting":"red"},{"name":"scale_min","setting":"15"},{"name":"scale_type","setting":"linear"},{"name":"x_axis_label","setting":"Weeks"}]

find = (i for i in data when i.name is 'x_axis_label')[0]

alert(find.setting)
```

[Demo](http://coffeescript.org/#try:data%20=%20%5B%7B%22name%22:%22color%22,%22setting%22:%22red%22%7D,%7B%22name%22:%22scale_min%22,%22setting%22:%2215%22%7D,%7B%22name%22:%22scale_type%22,%22setting%22:%22linear%22%7D,%7B%22name%22:%22x_axis_label%22,%22setting%22:%22Weeks%22%7D%5D%0A%0Afind%20=%20%28i%20for%20i%20in%20data%20when%20i.name%20is%20%27x_axis_label%27%29%5B0%5D%0A%0Aalert%28find.setting%29)

Comment: That is awesome, and why I am really starting to love Coffeescript

Answer (score 10):

I always prefer a 'multi language' solution over a 'idiomatic' solution. Thus you can to use `Array.filter`

```
data = [{"name":"color","setting":"red"},{"name":"scale_min","setting":"15"},{"name":"scale_type","setting":"linear"},{"name":"x_axis_label","setting":"Weeks"}]
find = (data.filter (i) -> i.name is 'x_axis_label')[0]
alert find.setting
```

Answer (score 8):

If you happen to be using Underscore.js, you can use [`find`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#find):

```
xAxisLabel = _.find data, (datum) -> datum.name is 'x_axis_label'
```